# Changing the context of a self-executing function

Tags: javascript, singleton

This code is copied directly from:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2264-Changing-The-Execution-Context-Of-Your-Self-Executing-Function-Blocks-In-JavaScript.htm

```
// Set the singleton value to the return value of the self-
// executing function block.
var singleton = (function(){

    // Declare a private variable.
    var message = "Stop playing with your context!";

    this.getMessage = function(){

        return( message );

    };


    // Return this object reference.
    return( this );

}).call( {} );

// alert the singleton message.
alert( "Message:", singleton.getMessage());
```

​My thought is that I can use this to better contain the variables and functions in my programs.

However, when I try to run the code in a JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSKHh/

It does not return the message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a plus sign instead of a comma in your alert.
Try like this:

```
alert( "Message:" + singleton.getMessage());
```

Comment: Wow ok I feel like I should take this question down and put a question up where I'm actually having a problem implementing this... Anyway, thank you

Comment: Care to mark the answer as accepted? :-)